# Apply a constant force to a SCNnode using sceneKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

using ARKit and SceneKit i'm try to make flying a Drone model.

for now successfully I can place the drone over a surface, simulate collision end detect contact between the base and the drone.

[image: Current situation]

Now I would like to try to fly this drone, apply some constant force!
(I don't want to simply move the Y axis to move up the drone) but I want to simulate a force pulling it up like it happen in the real life.

I started to write some code, and call this method once I press the up button..

```
// hit test and find object with specific name
    func applyForceToDrone() {
        print("tapped apply force drone at position ")
        
        let nodo = arrayDrone[0] // return the scnNode of the Drone in the scene
        let force = SCNVector3(0, 15, 0)
        
        print("appply force")
        nodo.physicsBody?.applyForce(force, asImpulse: false)
            
        
    }
```

resulting of this code is the drone jumping up and down every time I press the up button.
but this force need to be apply constant in the time ...

How can I constant apply a force to keep the drone up in the air? any tips how I can approach this problem ...

I can't find any example where a constant force is apply to an object.

thanks for the help.

Comment: I honeslty cannot tell you why it's jumping up and down only. I also used this applyForce command on some objects in one of my apps, but I needed the opposite, setting asImpulte = true. At this point you might run into some issues. Objects containing a dynamic physics body shall not be moved by anything else than the SCNPhysics engine. So if you want to let your drone fly and control the directions, you will need another approach. In the FOX example game from Apple you can find some approach how they control the character. Imagine the same for your drone, but in ARKit. It uses .kinematic body.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply force inside one of loop functions. To do so, define a variable var applyForce=false. Then on for example buttonUp touch begin,  set applyForce=true, on touch end set applyForce=false. Then inside loop function : if applyForce then do apply force. You have to tweak amount of force. Also you can add more parameters.